# Confused by partial derivatives

Tags: partial-derivative, implicit-differentiation

Right, I have a question here, about the following:

Use implicit differentiation to find the first and 2nd derivative.
$$x^{3/5}+y^{3/5} = 7$$

The answer is:
$$\begin{align}\frac{dy}{dx} &= -\frac{y^{2/5}}{x^{2/5}} \\[2ex] \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} &= \frac{2x^{3/5}+2y^{3/5}}{5x^{7/5}y^{1/5}} \end{align}$$

Now, I got the $dy/dx$ right, but I just can't the $d^2y/dx^2$ right! I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I differentiated for the 2nd time, I substituted the "$dy/dx$" with the value I got from the first part, continued and still got a different answer.

HELP, a detailed answer would be very helpful! How did the answer turn out to be like that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Normally 5x^7/5 would be read as $5\frac{x^7}5=x^7$; if you mean something else you should write it properly. And please put `$...$` around formulas. Type `$5x^{7/5}$` to get $5x^{7/5}$.

Comment: Got it, thank you for clearing that up, fixed it! ^^

Comment: Just to clarify, there are no partial derivatives here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Details of the calculus of the second derivative :

[image]